# How were the invaders programmed to shoot in the original arcade version of Space Invaders?

Tags: game-mechanics

I'm trying to make a clone of the original classic and mimic its game mechanics as closely as possible, but am stuck on making the invaders shoot.

From playing online versions of the game, it seems as though a random invader is chosen to shoot every x frames, then a random missile is chosen from the three available. x starts off as a random integer within a relatively-high range (say 300 - 600), then gradually decreases as the invaders are killed. Am I close?

Of course, I realise that no-one besides the original devs is likely to know this stuff for certain, but I'm hoping for an expert player to share what they've learned from simply playing the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Of course, I realise (sic) that no-one besides the original devs is likely to know this stuff for certain

That's not entirely true.  Computer Archeology has a write up that discusses the original Space Invaders assembly code. Here's a summary of information they present regarding the alien firing logic:

- There are three different alien shots in the game, each with a unique picture:

  - Object 2 is the "Rolling" shot &  spirals a bit as it falls.
  - Object 3 is the "Plunger" shot.
  - Object 4 is the "Squiggly" shot.
- The byte timer from Object 2 is used to synchronize the three shots so that only one shot is processed per screen.
- The common handler is responsible for moving each shot.

  - The normal delta Y for the shots is a constant 4 pixels down per step. A shot makes a step every 3 frames. (4 * 60/3 = 80 pixels per second).
  - If the number of aliens is reduced to 8 or less the delta changes up to 5 pixels per step (5*60/3 = 100 pixels per second).
- The common handler also initiates the alien shots. Each shot has a move-counter that starts with the shot & increments each step as it falls. The game keeps a constant reload rate that determines how fast the aliens can fire. The game takes the smallest count of the other two shots and compares it to the reload rate. If it is too soon since the last shot then no shot is fired.
- The reload rate gets faster as the game progresses. The code uses the upper two digits of the player's score as a lookup into a lookup table & sets the reload rate.
- Object 2 drops right over the player when it falls.
- The other two shots use pointers into a table of columns. The pointers advance very predictably. For instance object 4 shot will fall in columns 11, 1, 6, & 3 in that order.
- When there is only one alien left, object 3 is disabled & the other two are fired more often.

Additional details regarding the specific memory addresses, values, etc. are available [here](https://www.computerarcheology.com/Arcade/SpaceInvaders/).

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was hoping for and more! Now I have a definitive resource from which to glean not just the alien shooting logic, but **everything** that the original devs decided upon logic-wise, which was sorely missed until now. Thank you so much! :D